# Is it possible to trigger two AWS lambda function via a single SQS Message

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

As per my existing solution I have two lambda function which gets triggered by the different SQS message and create a folder structure in S3.

Now, I have the requirement where I need to use the single SQS message to trigger both the lambda function.

Is it possible to trigger multiple lambda function via a single SQS message if yes then can you please explain the process and how efficient it would be?

If is there any other approach I can follow please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: `S3 trigger --> SNS --> 2 x Lambda`. Or, if you particularly want SQS in there, `S3 trigger --> SNS --> 2 x SQS --> Lambda`

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that. The best way is to create [fan out](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-common-scenarios.html) setup with SNS + two SQS queues.

Otherwise, you have to develop other solution, e.g. one lambda gets triggered by sqs, and then invokes the second one passing the message as input.